# Uncaught ReferenceError: myajax is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick in WP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

**This code is for getting all posted post and its content using ajax in WP**

Function.php in WP

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action','data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action','data_fetch');

function data_fetch(){
   $this_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 10));
   if($this_query->have_posts()):
       while($this_query->have_posts()): $this_query->the_post(); ?>
           <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
           <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
   <?php endwhile;
       wp_reset_postdata();
   endif;
   die();
   }
```

index1.php in core WP folder Where actual error occur

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Ajax Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myajax(){
                $.post('/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {'action':'my_action'}, function(response){
                    $(#datafetch).append(response);
                });
            }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="datafetch">
            <button onclick="myajax()">Click Here</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error message in console is

*index1.php:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: myajax is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick*

Comment: this  `$(#datafetch)` should be under quotes .i.e: `$("#datafetch")` .

Comment: Ok i will try that

Comment: does that worked for you ?